# Style not getting applied first time

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

I am styling Grid Columns and there are some columns with custom template and some with default template.

The first time when I load the view the style is not applied to the columns with default template, but if I add/remove the columns in the grid (at runtime), I can see styling applied to all columns.

My code behind defines the following attached properties

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLinesBorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridLinesBorderBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(CarbonBlotter), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent));

public static readonly DependencyProperty GridLinesBorderThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GridLinesBorderThickness", typeof(Thickness), typeof(CarbonBlotter), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0)));

public SolidColorBrush GetGridLinesBorderBrush(UIElement element_)
{
  return (SolidColorBrush)element_.GetValue(GridLinesBorderBrushProperty);
}

public void SetGridLinesBorderBrush(UIElement element_, SolidColorBrush value_)
{
  element_.SetValue(GridLinesBorderBrushProperty, value_);
}

public Thickness GetGridLinesBorderThickness(UIElement element_)
{
  return (Thickness)element_.GetValue(GridLinesBorderThicknessProperty);
}

 private void ShowGridLines()
    {
      UserSettings.GridLineType gridLineType = _userSettings.ShowGridLines;
      Thickness gridLinesBorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 1, 1);
      if (gridLineType == UserSettings.GridLineType.Off)
      {
        SetGridLinesBorderThickness(_grid, new Thickness(0));
        SetGridLinesBorderBrush(_grid, Brushes.Transparent);
        SetAllowGridLines(_grid, false);
      }
      else (gridLineType == UserSettings.GridLineType.Black)
      {
        SetGridLinesBorderThickness(_grid, gridLinesBorderThickness);
        SetGridLinesBorderBrush(_grid, Brushes.Black);
        SetAllowGridLines(_grid, true);
      }      
    }
```

And on my Xaml I have a default template

```
<Style TargetType="ig:CellValuePresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ig:CellValuePresenter}}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Path=DataPresenter.(pwc:CarbonBlotter.GridLinesBorderThickness), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ig:CellValuePresenter}">
            <igw:CardPanel>
              <Border x:Name="MainBorder" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="4"/>
                      ...
```

And I have some custom templates which are based on default template

```
<Style x:Key="_columnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ig:CellValuePresenter}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ig:CellValuePresenter}}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <pwc:BlotterCashTradingLanguageBar/>
        </Border>
        ...
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And depending on the column name a default or custom template will be applied. And I am finding that the first time I launch the view, the columns with default template have no border lines, but if I change the view by adding few columns, the view gets refreshed and all the columns have the gridlines.

It looks like the default template is not picking the value from attached properties when the view loads first time.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, its weird, tried to set the attached properties from various places OnLoad, OnRender, from derived class using Property Override, nothing worked.

Created a new style with a key, made it based on default style. Where ever custom style is not availble used this new style. And it works.